# how to bring this message box to front using css/html/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image: system maintenance message box]

how to bring this message box to front using css/html/javascript as shown in picture

Comment: where's your code?

Comment: The system maintenance image is already in front of rest html content. 
However provide a valid code for better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use modal windows. This is a separate story for discussion.